# SharePoint Cross Domain REST Call from content Editor Web Part error

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, content-editor-web-part, cross-domain

**How to call cross domain rest call using SharePoint rest API 2013**

posting data in SharePoint list from https://qa.sp.scb.org/en/whoweare/diversity/Pages/Admin.aspx

To

http://qa.sp.scb.org/fr/whoweare/diversity/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CurrentTheme')/items(2)",

getting Error -Response to the preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://qa.sp.scb.org' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Code-

```
function AddListItemFrench() 

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://qa.sp.scb.org/fr/whoweare/diversity/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CurrentTheme')/items(2)",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            __metadata: {
                type: "SP.Data.Current_x0020_ThemeListItem"
            },

            Title: setTitle,
            ThemeTitle: ThemeHeading,
            Image: setImage,
            BgImage: setbgImage,
            Tag: hashtag,
            RightTheme: RightmenuHasTag,
            HashtagTitleFrench:Hashtagfrench,
            ThemeTitleFrench:Themetitlefrench
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
        },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            console.log(" Theme update in  French version");

            $("#slectedtheme").text(setTitle);

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("AddListItem is not update");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Using sp.js (JSOM) issue has been resolved

Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sp.js (JSOM) issue has been resolved

Code-

var siteUrl ='https://mysp.org/fr/inclusion/';

function updateListItemFrench() {

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Current Theme');

this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(2);

oListItem.set_item('Title', setTitle);
oListItem.set_item('Image', setImage );
oListItem.set_item('BgImage', setbgImage );
oListItem.set_item('RightTheme',  RightmenuHasTag );
oListItem.set_item('HashtagTitleFrench',  Hashtagfrench );
oListItem.set_item('ThemeTitleFrench', ThemeTitleFrench);

oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

console.log("Theme has been updated on french")

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

```
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
alert ("faild")
```

}